# How to skip table column in the format file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I don't want last column data in the output file. So, I am trying to skip the last column (ID_CARD) in the format file.But i am not getting the proper output. Just want to confirm is it the right way?

before skipping:

```
68      SQLCHAR             0       3       ""       68    PBP_ID                       Latin1_General_BIN

69      SQLCHAR             0       25      ""       69    PREVENTIVE_SERVICES          Latin1_General_BIN

70      SQLCHAR             0       216     ""       70    FILLER4                      Latin1_General_BIN

71      SQLCHAR             0       11      "\r\n"   71    ID_CARD_NO                   Latin1_General_BIN
```

Trying to skip:

```
68      SQLCHAR             0       3       ""       68    PBP_ID                       Latin1_General_BIN

69      SQLCHAR             0       25      ""       69    PREVENTIVE_SERVICES          Latin1_General_BIN

70      SQLCHAR             0       216     ""       70    FILLER4                      Latin1_General_BIN

71      SQLCHAR             0       0      ""        0        ID_CARD_NO                   Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: sorry for that. fixed.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the 71th row in format file as specified in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx

Comment: Is your delimiter really this `""`. Can you show the data file you are trying to import?

Comment: I have tried that but then i am getting an error like this:Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]The number of fields provided for bcp operation is less than the number of columns on the server.

Comment: actually this is the bcp out step, trying to fetch data from table into a file based on the format file...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to skip the column as per specified in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx):

First way is to set the "prefix length," "host file data length," and "server column order" to 0

```
68      SQLCHAR             0       3       ""       68    PBP_ID                       Latin1_General_BIN

69      SQLCHAR             0       25      ""       69    PREVENTIVE_SERVICES          Latin1_General_BIN

70      SQLCHAR             0       216     ""       70    FILLER4                      Latin1_General_BIN

71      SQLCHAR             0       0      ""        0        ID_CARD_NO                   Latin1_General_BIN
```

which you have already tried and the second one is deleting the whole row:

```
9.0
70
....

68      SQLCHAR             0       3       ""       68    PBP_ID                       Latin1_General_BIN

69      SQLCHAR             0       25      ""       69    PREVENTIVE_SERVICES          Latin1_General_BIN

70      SQLCHAR             0       216     ""       71    FILLER4                      Latin1_General_BIN
```

Note in this case you have to reduce total no. of rows to be imported i.e. `71` will become `70` in the header but in `server column order` i.e. 3rd last column it will retain the column order viz. `71`.

Comment: for first option, getting this error:SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Host-file columns may be skipped only when copying into the Server

Comment: while trying second option, getting this error:SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]The number of fields provided for bcp operation is less than the number of columns on the server.

Comment: Meanwhile, searching for solution found this link:http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/584001/bcp-table-out-with-format-file-does-not-work-if-file-specifies-less-columns-than-source-table

Comment: Are you importing or exporting data?

Comment: Try second option once again I have edited the format file and tell me what happens .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37306/discussion-between-snyder-and-praveenks)